# Find rows with same ID and have a particular set of names

Tags: sql, database, group-by

EDIT:

I have a table with 3 rows like so.

```
ID    NAME REV
1     A    0
1     B    0
1     C    0
2     A    1
2     B    0
2     C    0
3     A    1
3     B    1
```

I want to find the ID wich has a particular set of Names and the REV is same
example:
Edit2: GBN's solution would have worked perfectly, but since i do not have the access to create new tables. The added constraint is that no new tables can be created.

```
if input = A,B then output is 3
if input = A ,B,C then output is 1 and not 1,2 since the rev level differs in 2.
```

Comment: This is called relational division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to compare a COUNT per ID with the number of elements in your list:

```
SELECT
   ID
FROM
   MyTable
WHERE
   NAME IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY
   ID
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Note: ORDER BY isn't needed and goes after the HAVING if needed

Edit, with question update. In MySQL, it's easier to use a separate table for search terms

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gbn;
CREATE TABLE gbn (ID INT, `name` VARCHAR(100), REV INT);
INSERT gbn VALUES (1, 'A', 0);
INSERT gbn VALUES (1, 'B', 0);
INSERT gbn VALUES (1, 'C', 0);
INSERT gbn VALUES (2, 'A', 1);
INSERT gbn VALUES (2, 'B', 0);
INSERT gbn VALUES (2, 'C', 0);
INSERT gbn VALUES (3, 'A', 0);
INSERT gbn VALUES (3, 'B', 0);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gbn1;
CREATE TABLE gbn1 ( `name` VARCHAR(100));
INSERT gbn1 VALUES ('A');
INSERT gbn1 VALUES ('B');

SELECT
   gbn.ID
FROM
   gbn
   LEFT JOIN
   gbn1 ON gbn.`name` = gbn1.`name`
GROUP BY
   gbn.ID
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gbn1)
   AND MIN(gbn.REV) = MAX(gbn.REV);

INSERT gbn1 VALUES ('C');

SELECT
   gbn.ID
FROM
   gbn
   LEFT JOIN
   gbn1 ON gbn.`name` = gbn1.`name`
GROUP BY
   gbn.ID
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gbn1)
   AND MIN(gbn.REV) = MAX(gbn.REV);
```

Edit 2, without extra table, use a derived (inline) table:

```
SELECT
   gbn.ID
FROM
   gbn
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 'A' AS `name`
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'C'
   ) gbn1 ON gbn.`name` = gbn1.`name`
GROUP BY
   gbn.ID
HAVING
   COUNT(*) = 3 -- matches number of elements in gbn1 derived table
   AND MIN(gbn.REV) = MAX(gbn.REV);
```

Comment: @David Stratton: Your ORDER BY was in the wrong place. And would fail if you used SQL_MODE "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY".

Comment: The OP seems to want exact division.

Comment: Have edited the question . I did think of your answer but didnot do it because of the added constraint in the problem which i forgot to mention

Comment: Thanks!.. great idea. Wil look it through and let you know if this works

Comment: Okay. ! tried to work on it. And i think your idea would've done it. But turns out i dont have access to create a new table on the clients Database. Any way we could do this without using another table?

Comment: @gbn. thanks gbn..See my post. I solved it, there was one flaw that came out of min=max that i fixed as explained. Thanks again!

Comment: @GBN.. sure, just edit your query and add groupby ID,rev to make it perfect and i'l do that :-)

Comment: @GBN wouldve edited, but i dont have the privelage :P 
See my post for why the added groupby

Comment: I understand the GROUP BY reason, but even if this answer isn't exact for your needs, it did inspire and help you.

Comment: yes agreed!! :) but i wanted to tick the correct answer no. So that someone else gets the right answer when he sees it. In ne case ticking it :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to gbn, but allowing for the possibility of duplicate ID/Name combinations:

```
SELECT ID
FROM MyTable
WHERE NAME IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

OKAY!... I solved my problem ! I modified GBN's logic to do it without a search table using the IN clause

1 flaw with doing MAX(rev) = MIN(REV) is: if i have a data like so .

```
ID    NAME   REV
1     A      0
1     B      1
1     A      1
```

then when I use a query like

```
Select ID from TABLE
where NAME in {A,B}
groupby ID
having count(*) = 2
and MIN(REV) = MAX(REV)
```

it will not show me the ID 1 as the min and max are different and the count is 3.

So i simply add another column to the groupby

so the final query is

```
Select ID from TABLE
where NAME in {A,B}
groupby ID,REV
having count(*) = 2
and MIN(REV) = MAX(REV)
```

Thanks,to all that helped. !

Comment: It was simpler than i thought!